# The screen goes blank after using force:createRecord

Tags: lightning

I am creating a new contact from one of my flows using the function below

```
insertNewContact: function (component, event, helper){
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    var docId = component.get("v.recordId");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact__c",
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire(); 
},
```

I create a `Contact` record and save. Instead of closing the modal & redirecting to parent screen, the entire screen goes blank until I refresh the page.

Can I use `refreshView` in this case?

Comment: upvote this idea, there are a few solutions here. Give them a try https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VnmQAE

Comment: Also instead of using the force:createrecord event try using force:recordedit component tie it up with force:recordSaveSuccess event to refresh the screen

Comment: force:recordedit requires a record Id, how can that be bypassed and used for create?

Comment: my bad i did not see it was a createrecordevent, you may have to create your own custom component where in a button calls a modal (embed component inside the modal) to mimic the create record. with custom component you have full control on redirect using navigatetourl or window.location method

Comment: Hi @Nidhi, Any luck on this issue?